# What is the difference between removePersistentStore and destroyPersistentStoreAtURL?

Tags: ios, core-data

This isn't much information at all in the documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nspersistentstorecoordinator/1468907-removepersistentstore

https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nspersistentstorecoordinator/1468888-destroypersistentstoreaturl

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- `removePersistentStore:error:` removes the store from the persistent store coordinator. It's not available to use by the app, but the persistent store file is still there and could be re-added.
- `destroyPersistentStoreAtURL:withType:options:error:` removes all traces of the persistent store file. You could use `NSFileManager` methods, but you'd have to know some details about the persistent store file to wipe it out completely. Some are documented-- like the names of the journal file(s). Some are not documented-- like the location and names of external binary files. This method gets everything.